# Как отправлять данные POST,при изменение опции селекта?

Tags: php, jquery

Нужно определять, что именно пользователь выбрал в селекте и отправить id выбранной опции.Я добился получения id, пихаю его в инпут,но отправляется он только если сделать функцию клика по кнопке -

```
$(".add_mat").click( function() {
$.post("materials.php" , $("#materials").serialize());
});
```

А мне нужно, что работало так -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.material').on('change', function() {
var id_mat = this.value;
alert(id_mat);
$(".id_mat").val(id_mat);
$.post("materials.php" , $("#materials").serialize());
});
```

Не подскажите-ка реализовать?)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function pickUp(el){
  var option = el.val();
            $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: "materials.php",
                     data: {option: option}       
             });
}
```

```html
<select name="select" onchange="pickUp($(this));" >
  <option value="matherial 1">matherial 1</option>
  <option value="matherial 2">matherial 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Может,что-то делаю не так,но когда переменная пост пустая - array (size=0)
empty